# python can't get nested modules being imported

Tags: python, module, python-import, importerror

I've the next folder structure (btw Python 3.7):

```
roots_folder/                     
    main.py/                
    vk/              
        vk.py
    sa/
        sa.py
```

**main.py** files goes like this:

```
...
import vk

def main():
    vk.test()   ---->  module 'vk' has no attribute 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**vk.py** files itself:

```
def test():
    print('test worked')
```

I cannot understand the logic behind all this import thing. I've tried many variations based on lots of other answers, but it simply doesn't work.

If someone could suggest some kind of solution or point me towards how it's generally should be working, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Get rid of those `vk` and `sa` folders and move the `.py` files up a level. Why did you even have those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import will attempt to call the _ _ init _ _.py file within the module. You however do neither have that file, nor is it calling the vk.py file.

Simply renaming your vk.py to _ _ init _ _.py worked for me.

For more info on the way the import system works check out the Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html